# Error when passing variable into Block and NumberForm

Tags: associations

I made this pseudo-code that highlights what is happening. Assume the following dictionary:

```
etable = {0.00,0.00034357,0.0018014,0.00438828,0.00804415,0.0126834,0.0181973,0.0244566,0.0313147,0.0386107,0.0461737,0.0538263,0.0613893,0.0686853,0.0755434,0.0818027,0.0873166,0.0919558,0.0956117,0.0981986,0.0996564,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55,0.60,0.65,0.70,0.75,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.95,1.00};

enumdict = 
  AssociationThread[
    etable,
    Table[x, {x, 100, 100 + Length[etable] - 1}]
  ]
```

Now if we pass a table of values containing some of the keys directly we get the desired output:

```
enumdict[NumberForm[#, {2, 2}]]& /@ Table[x,{x, 0.05, 0.50, 0.05}]
```

> {121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130})

If I pass the values into a block like this and then use loops, if the value for the comes from a sum we can get an error

```
testfunc[\[Epsilon]_, ev_] :=
  Block[{},
    Return[
      ToString[enumdict[NumberForm[\[Epsilon]+ev,{2,2}]]]
    ];
  ]

Do[
  Print[testfunc[x,0.05]];,
  {x, 0.05, 0.50, 0.05}
]
```

> 122
> 123
> 124
> 125
> 126
> Missing[KeyAbsent, 0.35]
> 128
> 129
> 130
> 131

However, if we set the additive variable to 0 it works

```
Do[
  Print[testfunc[x,0.0]];,
  {x, 0.05, 0.50, 0.05}]
```

> 121
> 122
> 123
> 124
> 125
> 126
> 127
> 128
> 129
> 130

What is going on here?

Comment: At a glance, I'd say it's probably a rounding / numerical precision issue. I would think it a bad idea to use machine-precision numbers as keys in an association.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the suggestion. Assuming it was a rounding error I found a solution that seems to work. Ill post it soon.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, machine numbers are not exact. Consider the full form of your test keys:

```
(t=Table[x, {x, 0.05, 0.50, 0.05}]) // FullForm
```

[image]

Now let us define a test association with the third and seventh element of t:

```
assoc = <|t[[3]] -> "ok", t[[7]] -> "ok"|>;
```

The error in t[[3]] is still tolerated:

```
assoc[0.15]

ok
```

However, the error on t[[7]] is too large:

```
assoc[0.35]

Missing["KeyAbsent", 0.35]
```

Well what can you do about this? The cure is to use rational numbers!

Answer (score 0):

Using string instead of the actual numbers solves the problem.

Thank you for the suggestions.

`enumdict[ToString[NumberForm[#, {2, 2}]]] & /@ Table[x,{x, 0.05, 0.50, 0.05}];`

`testfunc[\[Epsilon]_, ev_] := Block[{},Return[ToString[enumdict[ToString[NumberForm[\[Epsilon]+ev,{2, 2}]]]]];]`